# Limiting case of of integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{1+(\arctan x)^n} $ then,

Evaluate $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.$

ATTEMPT:

Here $$I=\int _o^\infty \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cos x}{1 + (\arctan x)^n} \, dx.$$

Clearly $f(x)$ is **non- integrable** in this case.

I  tried the following substitution:

Let $\arctan x=t$

$dx=\sec^2t \, dt$

So $$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cos(\tan t) \sec^2t}{1+t^n} \, dt.$$

But this again is **non-integrable**

I believe there is some other approach for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$, we have $\arctan(x)<1$ for $0<x<\tan(1)$.  For $x>\tan(1)$, $\arctan(x)>1$.  Thus,

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\cos x,& 0<x<\tan(1)\\\\
0,&x>\tan(1)
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore,

$$\int_0^{\infty}f(x) dx=\sin(\tan(1))$$

Answer (score 2):

Simply compute your function $f$, and then plug it into the integral.

For $x > \tan 1$ you have $\arctan x > 1$, so $(\arctan x)^n+1 \to + \infty$. 
This means that $f(x) = 0$ for $x > \tan 1$.

Clearly, for $0 < x < \tan 1$ you have the same argument, and $f(x)=\cos x$, and finally $f( \tan 1)$ does not matter for the integral.

So
$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_0^{\tan 1}\cos x \ \ dx = \sin (\tan 1)$$

Comment: But the answer is $sin(tan1).$ not $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$

Comment: @yasir Please see my comment.

Comment: Oh, you all are right! I confused $\tan$ with $\arctan$.

Comment: @Crostul No worry.  My eyes have done worse to me.  ;-))